# Why the content encoding is not set by Browsers when i upload a text/plain UTF-8 encoded file?

Tags: file-upload, browser, character-encoding, multipartform-data, mime

When I upload a text file that has UTF-8 encoded characters, I see that the charset is missing in the Content-Type. I see this behavior both in chrome and firefox. The problem is on the server I am trying to parse using javax.mail library which defaults the encoding to US-ASCII if charset is not specified.

Why the Browsers are not setting the charset?

[pic of multipart request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnKsz.png)